# Provide resource monitoring for argo-workflow

Tags: prometheus, grafana, monitoring, rancher, argo-workflows

My current setup is a cluster with rke2 and rancher. With rancher, I have deployed the cattle-monitoring-system, which setup Prometheus and Grafana with multiple useful dashboards.

In a next step, I've also deployed the Argo-Workflow application to support compute intense workflows, which a colleague uses. Unfortunately, Argo doesn't provide any information about the resource usage of a workflow. To address this, I'd like to grant my colleague access to Grafana and the necessary dashboards through rancher. However, it appears that basic users in Rancher don't have the permission to view Grafana.

How can I configure a basic-user in rancher to view his project/namespace resource metrics in Grafana?